# CUDA enabled audio transcoding software?

Tags: audio, cuda, transcode

I have 2000 files which iTunes somehow decided should be aac and transcoded for me without me realizing it. I want to transcode these back to MP3s as quickly as possible, so I can use them on Google Music.

I have a Core 2 quad core running at 2.9 GHz, and I have a few year old CUDA enabled video card (GTX 260). I'm happy to use either or both to get the job done ASAP. Currently I'm using Handbrake, but I wonder if CUDA might be quicker.

Comment: Transcoding to mp3 should be pretty fast on a recent CPU, maybe 30x realtime? In which case it should only take a couple of hours for 2000 files, less if your transcoder uses all 4 cores, or you split it into 4 batches of 500 and run them simultaneously (from commandline etc)

Comment: Just remember, if iTunes transcoded (probably already encoded) files to AAC and you transcode them back again, you will definitely lose quality.

Comment: Yeah the program that I found was giving me a horrible ETA, I guess. Must have been based on some hard coded and outdated estimate, rather than my real power. It utilized all four cores automatically and pounded through it in a couple hours.